# apache jena tdbloader2 illegal escape sequence value

Tags: jena, turtle-rdf

I am trying to insert several ttl files with the `tdbload2` v1.3.6 command. During installation i get the following error;  what can I do to fix it?

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1306503, col: 56] illegal escape sequence value: n (0x6E)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:169)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:116)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectItem(LangTurtleBase.java:299)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectList(LangTurtleBase.java:280)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:271)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:210)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:47)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RiotReader.parse(RiotReader.java:116)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RiotReader.parse(RiotReader.java:93)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RiotReader.parse(RiotReader.java:66)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.bulkloader2.CmdNodeTableBuilder.exec(CmdNodeTableBuilder.java:163)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:101)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:63)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:50)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.bulkloader2.CmdNodeTableBuilder.main(CmdNodeTableBuilder.java:81)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version?  It helps align the line numbers.

Check line 1306503 and see what it says.  I guess there is a \n in a URI.

Comment: v1.3.6. I am loading 10 files at once. i dont know where this line is.